# How do you give estimates for Magento upgrade?

Tags: magento

I am interested to know how do you measure the needed time for Magento upgrade?
I guess, that most of you had hard time to answer on the client's question: "How long it will take to upgrade my Magento store?"

Usually the client needs to hear just a number for e.g.:
"It will take X hours and it will cost Y bucks."

The main idea behind the question is about the technical side
and what do you check as developer to make your own calculations for Magento upgrades.

I created the next check list, just for my own calculations:

- Is the Magento core touched?
- Is the Magento DB schema touched?
- Do we have inconsistent data in the DB?
- How many custom extensions are installed in local and community code pool?
- Are the custom extension compatible with the latest version of Magento?
- Did the theme developer used local.xml file for the the layout directives,
  or just copied xml files from the base/default/layout to the layout directory
  of the custom theme?
- Do we have deprecated layout directives / block methods in the layout xml files?
- Have I developed this Magento shop?

Do you think, that I am missing something and if yes, would you like to share with me and the community your additional points for the check list?

Comment: Interesting question - Its probably going to get closed though which is a shame

Comment: It's not programming related but I'll bite.  You tell your client your hourly rate is $X, and you'll attack the problem of their upgrade as quickly as possible, and charge them $X * the number of hours the upgrade takes, with the option to set a cap on the hours where progress can be checked at and a decision to move forward can  be made.  If they want a more specific estimate suggest they ask the people who customized their shop to give them that estimate.

Comment: @DrewHunter I hope, that it makes sense for the most of readers.

Comment: @DrewHunter Ya if it gets closed, post it on quora.  This is important content.

Comment: @AlanStorm thank you! I've never tried it on your way. I think, that your suggestion will really work, when  I work with the direct client. I will give it a try in my next Magento upgrade.

Comment: @ceckoslab It requires a lot of trust between you and your client — but those are the only relationships worth having (in my opinion)

Comment: I don't believe you can ask those questions to any customer... they likely won't know or if they do they will be wrong. That's my experience. Either by ignorance or because it was fooled by a third party. In your case if the shop wasn't build by me, I would charge a fee to give the estimate, ask for full remote access to the installation and check it by myself. Get same original version & run diff on sql schema, code, etc and find the answers myself. Think how much time would take you to find that information and charge for that time to yet provide an estimate.

Comment: @Valor do you talk about the first comment of Alan Storm?

Comment: Pretty much what Alan said, and to be honest, there are many areas of Magento where this type estimate should be used. It is way too easy to sour a relationship because you gave an estimate based on code you hadn't looked at yet.. only to realize that "previous developers" left a mess somewhere. I like the idea of doing standard discovery. Charge them two hours to look over the site, see what gremlins may exist, and then give them an estimate after you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: @ceckoslab no, it was regarding your question

Comment: @Valor I think, that you didn't get my point correctly. This checklist is a list of questions, that you have to ask yourself before to give any estimate. I edited the question. Please read the question again and let me know if my point doesn't make sense for you.

Comment: @ceckoslab I did not said it doesn't make sense your point. I mean that it doesn't make sense to GUESS those questions or take for granted customer information about those questions. But not the questions itself, those questions are very good and I agree with each one of those. Just said that for the estimate to be accurate, only yourself can answer those questions.

Comment: Given the unlimited variety of server configurations people try to run it on, Magento's vaunted wish to be everything for everybody, module installs, and access to source code by everyone from professionals to "cargo cult" tinkerers... There's no real way but Alan Storm's recommendation. It takes as long as it takes and dry runs should be done on a test server till you get it functional there. Given the unlimited variety of server configurations, this gets you into the ballpark when you put it on the live server, there will always be a last couple stumbling blocks before it's complete.

Comment: As a further note, it's common practice among those cold call Magento specialists to offer a $1000 health check as an upgrade prerequisite before they'll quote for the actual upgrade. I've gotten four of them annoying me over the phone or through email in the last six months.

Comment: +1 @AlanStorm. I'd say the same thing goes for rescuing and bug fixing a site abandoned by previous developers. If the client isn't happy with the approach after explaining the reasons, it's probably not worth touching the project.

Answer (score 2):

out of topic really but divide the work at least to two portions:

1. upgrading magento code and database schema (disabling all customisations this usually takes 1 - 4hours dependant of the database size and your IO speed)
2. migrating theme files to new structure (if they are based on magento defaults)
3. upgrading extensions one by one (if they need upgrading)
4. agree on amount of testing
5. and sell a good development pipeline

and before giving a client quote you analyse the time that you need to spend on migrating themes by diffing your theme to upgraded base theme and layouts and also make a map of installed extensions and their versions and local overwrites.

$$$$